# BGE get controller/joystick count in python

Tags: python, game-engine

I am making bge games and want them full controller support and I have already scripted the input, but the axis and the buttons index is changing when having different amount of controllers. Here is what I mean:

```
#joystick for buttons, joystickaxis for axis

#2 controller

#controller 1
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[1]

#controller 2
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[1]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[0]

#4 controller 

#controller 4
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[3]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
#controller 3
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[2]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[1]
#controller 2
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[1]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[2]
#controller 2
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[3]

#3 controller

#controller 3
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[2]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
#controller 2
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[1]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[1]
#controller 1
joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[2]

#1 controller

joystick = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
joystickaxis = bge.logic.joysticks[0]
```

Now I need my script to know how many controllers are registered in bge and I would like to know if there is a python function for that, I mean bge seems at least to know how many there are.

Comment: Just to let you know: Code repetition is no good design. It makes development and maintenance really hard. I suggest to use common programming techniques, like looping, encapsulation, parameters and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bge.logic.joysticks` gives a list of the max number of controllers (eight), now if there is not a controller the list will have None in that slot.

All you need to do is count how many not None items are in that list, or what I did, count how many are None.

```
connected_controllers  = 8 - bge.logic.joysticks.count(None)
```

Since we know there are always eight controller slots, it counts how many are "None" and subtracts that from 8. Quite simple really.

Comment: len(bge.logic.joysticks) - bge.logic.joysticks.count(None)

Comment: @Monster that is essentially the same as what I have. Except because the controller list is 8 I skip that check.

Comment: It is just a modification of your snippet (thanks for that hint). The modification avoids to hard-code the amount of possible joysticks.